# Is there a simple way to have separate dock icons for different Chrome Profiles?

Tags: macos, dock, google-chrome, settings

I am using [Google Chrome](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/) version 22 on OS X 10.8. I use separate user profiles (created using the native Chrome facility in `Settings->Users`) for my "regular" web browsing, and the web development that I do. I launch my web development profile from the regular Chrome profile window by clicking on the avatar in the top-left-hand-corner:

[image]

At the moment both of these profiles share a single dock icon. However, I would much prefer for each Chrome profile to have its own dock icon, with the windows managed separately - and ideally for the dock icons to be distinguished in some way. Is this easily possible? By 'easy', I mean things like rebuilding Chrome from source are not an option I'll consider.

**Note**: I would like to use the same, stable, version of Chrome for both profiles. It would be OK to have the same version installed twice as long as they can be kept separate and the dock icon distinguished.

Comment: I just want to point out this is a standard feature of Chrome on Windows (at least in v64). When you create a new profile in Chrome `Settings->Users` Chrome asks "Create a Desktop Shortcut for this User" and if you click yes it creates a shortcut that's the Chrome icon with the user's Chrome profile icon overlaid in the bottom right corner. When the app is running each profile has its own icon in the taskbar. I only bring this up because I'm hoping they eventually bring that feature to the macOS version.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For having two Chrome running at the same time you need to create a second runnable Google Chrome App.

You can create that second application by running the following script. It comes from [this site](https://thoughts.duoconsulting.com/blog/multiple-profiles-google-chrome-os-x), I copy and paste for readers' convenience:

```
#!/bin/bash

PROFILE_NAME=$1
mkdir -p "/Applications/Google Chrome $1.app/Contents/MacOS"

F="/Applications/Google Chrome $1.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome $1"
cat > "$F" <<\EOF
#!/bin/bash

#
# Google Chrome for Mac with additional profile.
#

# Name your profile:
EOF

echo "PROFILE_NAME='$PROFILE_NAME'\n" >> "$F"

cat >> "$F" <<\EOF
# Store the profile here:
PROFILE_DIR="/Users/$USER/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/${PROFILE_NAME}"

# Find the Google Chrome binary:
CHROME_APP=$(mdfind 'kMDItemCFBundleIdentifier == "com.google.Chrome"' | head -1)
CHROME_BIN="$CHROME_APP/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome"
if [[ ! -e "$CHROME_BIN" ]]; then
  echo "ERROR: Can not find Google Chrome.  Exiting."
  exit -1
fi

# Start me up!
exec "$CHROME_BIN" --enable-udd-profiles --user-data-dir="$PROFILE_DIR"
EOF

sudo chmod +x "$F"
```

Save it in a file (let's say `create_second_chrome.sh` in the Desktop folder), open the shell and execute it by passing as parameter the profile folder you want to associate to the second Chrome App. It will be called `Google Chrome profile_folder_name`. Let's suppose `Google Chrome Development`:

```
$ cd ~/Desktop
$ . create_second_chrome.sh Development
```

Now you can launch the new version of Chrome (`Google Chrome Development`) from the `~/Applications` directory. You can set a different icon by right-clicking on the app and selecting 'Get Info'. You will see that this new version has its own icon on the dock and can be docked there if needed.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. I created a new profile for myself called `Development` in `Settings -> Users`. This created the directory `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Profile 2`. However, executing `open -a "Google Chrome" --args --profile-directory="Profile 2"` still opens the old/original profile, as I can tell from the avatar in the top-right corner.

Comment: @AndrewFerrier Have you tried to close `command + q` Chrome and repopen it by means of the workflow? It works with me.

Comment: it works if you do that, yes (i.e. if Chrome is not started at all, it opens the desired profile). But if one profile is already started, executing that command re-opens a window for that profile, irrespective of which profile is specified. That's doesn't help with the question, since the objective is to have both open simultaneously.

Comment: @AndrewFerrier Thanks for your edit, now the answer it better! Hope it helped you! Luca

Comment: @AndrewFerrier Would you like to have two different icons? Correct me if I'm wrong but the icons should be the only problem right?

Comment: @AndrewFerrier I tried to modify the icon (`command`+`i` on the new App and drag and drop on the right of the Google Chrome Development name) of the second Chrome and I'm not experiencing that problem.

Comment: neither am I now! Seems I made a mistake, it seems OK now. Will leave it running for a bit, see if I continue to experience problems...

Comment: While copying the icon worked in the Finder and OSX application switcher, it doesn't seem to have worked in Activity Monitor or Witch. I'm guessing those tools look at the process rather than the app bundle for the icon. Any thoughts on how to fix that?

Comment: It seems that it works in all cases except drag'n'droping links. When dnd'ing "real" Chrome opens them even if the drop target was other app instance.

Comment: I'm seeing something similar to @AndreyTatarinov.  If I try to send a URL to the wrapped Chrome, it briefly opens what looks like another instance of the wrapped chrome, which quits immediately.  The wrapped Chrome opens a new window with the default page (not the URL I was trying to open).  This means that the wrapped Chrome doesn't work with, for example, Choosy.  I think it has something to do with LaunchServices not recognizing the wrapped version as an independent application, but I've tried adding an Info.plist with a different `CFBundleIdentifier` and that didn't fix the problem.

Comment: Hi @Maverik, I think this script mistakes what the `--user-data-dir` option points to.  It points something called `PROFILE_DIR ` to `/Users/$USER/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/${PROFILE_NAME}` as if the profile were a chrome user.  But in reality this needs to be up one level.  I think you should call it `CHROME_DATA` or `INSTANCE_DATA` and you should put it at `/Users/$USER/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome${PROFILE_NAME}`: alongside the existing `Chrome` directory, not inside it.

Comment: I ran into an issue where the icon was reverting back to default randomly. And I needed the process name to be different to use some other scripts. I've added a symlink in the Chrome app to fix this. Replace the exec call in the answer script with this:

`# Create a symlink in the Google Chrome app so we control the process name
SYMLINK="$CHROME_APP/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome ${PROFILE_NAME}"
if [[ ! -e "$SYMLINK" ]]; then
 ln -s "$CHROME_APP/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome" "$SYMLINK"
fi

# Start me up!
exec "$SYMLINK" --enable-udd-profiles --user-data-dir="$PROFILE_DIR"`

Comment: I'm finding on M1 macs this launches as an intel app in activity monitor

Comment: (which is considerably slower)

Answer (score 6):

**UPDATE**:❗️ I no longer use this method.  For a while I used [Epichrome](https://github.com/dmarmor/epichrome) which is much easier to use and works better, and I posted a [new answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/325358/89069) with this information, but Epichrome is no longer maintained. I have also tried WebCatalog but at the moment I'm not happy with any of the options I know about.

---

*Original answer with manual instructions:*

I tried the script from @Maverick and it partly worked (thanks!) but I ran into some difficulties.  The main problem is that the wrapped copy of Chrome, although it is independent, has its own icon, and works correctly on its own, cannot open URLs sent from other applications, so it doesn't work with Choosy.

Here is what worked for me, to get a second Chrome which can open links via Choosy, for example:

1. Copy `Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome` to `Library/Application Support/Google/ChromePersonal` in your home directory.
   This is optional; I wanted to transfer over my Chrome User profiles to the new instance.  But if you're OK starting fresh you can skip this.
2. Copy `Google Chrome.app` to another location.  I used `/Applications/Google Chrome Personal.app`.
3. Copy my wrapper.sh script (below) into the app's `Contents/MacOS` directory.
4. `chmod +x wrapper.sh`
5. Modify `Contents/Info.plist` in this new app to:

   - point to the wrapper script (set `CFBundleExecutable` value to `wrapper.sh`)
   - have a unique `CFBundleIdentifier` (just add "Personal" to the existing value)
   - have a unique `CFBundleName` (just add "Personal" to the existing value)
   - have a unique `CFBundleDisplayName` (just add "Personal" to the existing value)

Here is my modified wrapper.sh script.  Put it at `/Applications/Google\ Chrome\ Personal.app/Contents/MacOS/wrapper.sh` and then edit the Info.plist as in step 4.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Wrapper script that starts independent instance of Google Chrome for Mac

# To use: copy Google Chrome.app to a new location.  Copy this script into
# the Contents/MacOS directory of the copied app.  Edit the copied app's
# Contents/Info.plist and change CFBundleExecutable to "wrapper.sh",
# and pick a unique CFBundleIdentifier.

# Instance data will be stored here.  You can copy your existing data 
# to this location if you want to preserve your existing user profile(s).
# You can also change this if you want to store the data somewhere else.
INSTANCE_DIR="/Users/$USER/Library/Application Support/Google/ChromePersonal"

# Find the Google Chrome binary:
CHOME_BIN="$(dirname "$0")/Google Chrome"

# Start Chrome
exec "$CHOME_BIN" --user-data-dir="$INSTANCE_DIR"
```

One caveat: I believe Chrome's auto-update feature will break this every time Chrome updates, meaning you need to re-do steps 3 and 4 after every Chrome update.

Comment: Following these instructions I get an app that won't launch

Comment: Sorry @TomJNowell!  I guess I must have missed a step.  Probably you have to chmod 755 the wrapper.sh script?  Mine is executable.  If you try that and it fixes the problem for you, let me know so I can update the answer?

Comment: chmod +x did the trick

Comment: You can prevent auto updates by changing the ``KSProductID`` key in ``Info.plist``. If you go to the about page, you'll see an "KSOmahaServer app 'com.google.ChromePersonal' info node status 'error-unknownApplication'. ..."; error when trying to manually update.

Comment: Follow-up: Updates seem to be disabled for me without changing ``KSProductID``. It says there's an update available, then I click Relaunch, and it relaunches to the same version. I don't have Automatic Updates for All Users enabled, so perhaps that's the reason or that I've renamed the executable.

Answer (score 3):

For a while I used [Epichrome](https://github.com/dmarmor/epichrome) for this purpose.  Epichrome is designed for creating site-specific browsers, but you can set up the filtering rules and the icon however you want, so it's perfectly capable of just creating a second Chrome with its own separate profile and dock icon.  Epichrome-created browsers do work with Google's update mechanism, so they will all stay up to date with the latest version of Chrome.

It has a simple GUI—no coding or recompiling of Chrome required.  It was a pretty solid solution for this problem, but ...

❗️ Epichrome is no longer maintained. I can no longer recommend this method. There are a number of other products in this area, some of which are listed in the Epichrome README as possible alternatives.

Comment: Have you compared Epichrome with [Detangle](https://github.com/google/detangle)?

Comment: Epichrome has been abandoned.

Answer (score 2):

None of these answers worked for me in a comprehensive way under Mac OS X Yosemite. Here is my solution, which gives you multiple instances, a dock launch menu for the instances, and different icons for each instance. When you run the script it'll automatically go through all your profiles, and then tell you what to do next.

```
#!/bin/bash

# cdi.sh - Make chrome profiles behave like multiple browsers on Mac OS X
#          (Tested on Yoshmite). Make profiles work like seperate applications
#          - esp. useful if you want to easily switch between different browsers
#          in different virtual desktops / workspaces, or don't want work
#          windows mixed in with home windows in the "Window" menu, or want to
#          be able to easily see what processes are with a certain profile in
#          chrome task manager, or be able to eaisly quit one profile with
#          multiple windows open and start where you left of later.

set -e

cd /Users/$USER/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome

CDI="cdi-chrome-multiple-profile-instances-in-dock-with-different-icons.d"
APPLESCRIPTS="$CDI/Applescript-Sources"
LAUNCHERS="$CDI/Chrome-Launchers"
RUNTIMES="$CDI/Chrome-Runtimes"
test -d $CDI || mkdir $CDI
test -d $APPLESCRIPTS || mkdir $APPLESCRIPTS
test -d $LAUNCHERS || mkdir $LAUNCHERS
test -d $RUNTIMES || mkdir $RUNTIMES

grep '"username"' Profile*/Preferences Default/Preferences | grep -v '               ' | awk -F : '{print $1";"$3}' | sed 's:/Preferences::g' | sed 's:\@:-at-:g' | sed 's/;\ /;/g' > $CDI/profiles.txt
# Like: Profile 1;"webmaster-at-example.org"

echo "Be patient, this involves copying a lot of data..."

while read PROFILE; do

DIR="$(echo $PROFILE | awk -F\; '{print $1}')"
# Like: DIR='Profile 1'
echo "Working on profile: $DIR"

LINK="$(echo $PROFILE | awk -F\; '{print $2}' | sed 's/\ /\-/g' | sed 's/"//g' | sed 's/^/cdi-profile-/g')"
# Like: cdi-profile-webmaster-at-example.org

APP="$(echo $LINK | sed 's/^cdi-profile-//g' | sed 's/$/-DO-NOT-RUN-DIRECTLY-JUST-USE-FOR-CHANGING-ICON-cdi\.app/g')"
# Like: webmaster-at-example.org-DO-NOT-RUN-DIRECTLY-JUST-USE-FOR-CHANGING-ICON-cdi.app

SHIM="$(echo $LINK | sed 's/^cdi-profile-//g' | sed 's/$/\.app/g')"
# Like: webmaster-at-example.org.app

TXT="$APPLESCRIPTS/$(echo $LINK | sed 's:^cdi-profile-:chrome-:g' | sed 's/$/\.txt/g')"
# Like:
# cdi-chrome-multiple-profile-instances-in-dock-with-different-icons.d
# /Applescript-Sources/chrome-webmaster-at-example.org.txt

test -L "$LINK" || ln -s "$DIR" "$LINK"
cd "$LINK"
test -L Default || ln -s . Default
cd /Users/$USER/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome
test -d "$RUNTIMES/$APP" || cp -R /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app "$RUNTIMES/$APP"

## This section disabled because enabling it makes automatic profile login not work.
## There is a chance someone who knows more about chrome will help at some point; see:
## https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=460787
## https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-discuss/0HEeMuh8WqA
## https://github.com/lhl/chrome-ssb-osx
# Change Bundle ID so desktop assignation works. Not sure if this will survive updates.
# CFBundleIdentifier must contain only alphanumeric (A-Z,a-z,0-9), hyphen (-), and period (.) characters.
# (Based on fiddling around there also seems to be a length limit.)
#UUID="$(echo $APP | md5sum | awk '{print $1}' | tr [0-9] [A-Z] | cut -c 1-4,29-32)"
#plutil -replace CFBundleIdentifier -string "cdi.$UUID" -- "$RUNTIMES/$APP/Contents/Info.plist"
#plutil -replace CFBundleName -string "$UUID" -- "$RUNTIMES/$APP/Contents/Info.plist"
#plutil -replace CFBundleDisplayName -string "$UUID" -- "$RUNTIMES/$APP/Contents/Info.plist"
#plutil -replace KSProductID -string "cdi.$UUID" -- "$RUNTIMES/$APP/Contents/Info.plist"
# To check: defaults read ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.spaces.plist app-bindings

echo "on run" > $TXT
echo -n "do shell script " >> $TXT
echo -n '"' >> $TXT
echo -n "/Users/$USER/Library/Application\\\\ Support/Google/Chrome/$RUNTIMES/$APP/Contents/MacOS/Google\\\\ Chrome --user-data-dir=/Users/$USER/Library/Application\\\\ Support/Google/Chrome/$LINK" >> $TXT
echo ' > /dev/null 2>&1 &"' >> $TXT
echo "quit" >> $TXT
echo "end run" >> $TXT
test -d "$LAUNCHERS/$SHIM" || osacompile -o "$LAUNCHERS/$SHIM" $TXT

done < $CDI/profiles.txt

echo
echo 'Done with automated portion. Now you should manually:'
echo
echo '1. Add (identical) icons of your choice to each pair of profile Launchers'
echo '   / Runtimes in the folder ~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/'
echo '   cdi-chrome-multiple-profile-instances-in-dock-with-different-icons.d'
echo '   (google for numerous guides on how to change mac os x app icons)'
echo
echo '2. From the finder, drag the "Chrome-Launchers" folder to the stacks area'
echo '   of the dock. Right click on the stack and select "List" for easy viewing.'
echo '   Also select "Display as Folder" and give the folder a nice icon.'
echo
echo '3. BE SURE to only open Chrome via this stack. DO NOT pin the app-area'
echo '   Chrome icon(s) to the app area of the dock! DO NOT run "normal" Chrome!'
echo
echo 'The only exception to (3) is if you need to add a new profile. In that case,'
echo 'close all instances, then open the "normal" Chrome, add profile, close, and'
echo 'then run this script again.'
echo
echo 'Note: when you launch first time you will get "Welcome to Google Chrome"'
echo '      dialog box. This is normal; do not worry. It will ask if you want'
echo '      to set Chrome as default; this applies to that instance of chrome.'
echo '      Choosy - http://www.choosyosx.com/ - works great with this!'
echo
```

For icons, you can use any PNG (or probably many other formats).

The chrome avatars which you may already be used to are located under "~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Avatars" - avatar_ninja.png etc.

Or make your own, or use one of the numerous icon sites - I like [Easyicon](http://www.easyicon.net/).

Also this looks possibly useful - [How to Get Back Avatars in Chrome to Switch User Profiles More Easily](http://digiwonk.wonderhowto.com/how-to/get-back-avatars-chrome-switch-user-profiles-more-easily-0159605/) - to make the open windows easier to quickly identify (untested).

One thing that isn't working yet is the ability to assign different user profile chrome instances to specific desktops. This is because if the attribute used to do this is changed, the browser is no longer able to automatically log in to that profile when the browser starts up. I've made a forum post and bug report on this issue; it is also a problem for site-specific browsers, so the chrome-ssb-osx project may get this working at some point. I don't have the 10 reputation points needed to include more than 2 links in posts here (help! :-), so you'll have to look at the links to these things in the script above ("This section disabled" section).

Comment: Since this is getting a bit complex, new stuff will all go to https://github.com/djbclark/chrome-apartheid

Answer (score 1):

I have found this answer from a [linked question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/338551/100490) and it works for me.

> Install [Chrome Beta](https://www.google.com/chrome/beta/) then you can run 2 completely separate chrome instances. Of course, from time to time there may be some bugs but 99% of the time it works well.

Comment: Which linked question?

Comment: this one -> https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/338551/is-there-a-way-to-open-separate-instance-of-chrome-where-cmd-q-doesnt-close-all?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment the main thread but here is my contribution:
On Apple Silicon (M3 for me), as Keegan 82 pointed out on https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/67050/511004, the solution makes it run on intel rather than arm and it's much slower, it even crashed when opening the 1Password plugin.
Solution for me was changing the script from

```
exec "$CHROME_BIN" --enable-udd-profiles --user-data-dir="$PROFILE_DIR"
```

to

```
env /usr/bin/arch -arm64 "$CHROME_BIN" --user-data-dir="$PROFILE_DIR" &
```

The main change is specifying the env.

I also removed --enable-udd-profiles as it doesn't seem to have any effect (maybe on earlier Chrome version).

I added '&' at the end to avoid having a leftover shell process open while Chrome is running.

Edit: the & also make the icon don't work, just so you know.

Comment: Where is Keegan82"s comment which answer - there is a share button under each answer that will give the url

Comment: Add it to the answer please, not as a comment. Don't think of the Q and all A as a 'thread'. There is no conversation going on, this isn't a forum. Each answer should be self contained and include all references if needed.

Comment: There is something wrong if it is running an Intel app on Apple Silicon, the given code should just be working. Have you done something to make your Terminal.app run as Intel?

Comment: No my terminal app is running on Silicon if I launch it manually but when launching in through the new chrome app created by the script it runs on Intel and looking at the script I don't see why.