# What makes an app unique from POV of options -> assign to desktop?

Tags: macos, dock, spaces, window-manager, mission-control

What is the set of things that differentiate one application from another from the point of view of right-click on dock icon -> Options -> Assign To (All Desktops / This Desktop / None)?

I've experimented and haven't been able to hit on a combination of actual binary name / Info.plist values / PkgInfo string that will make Mac OS X workspaces think a duplicated application is different from the original for purposes of automatic desktop assignment.

Answer (score -1):

Found it, just leaving this here to make it easier for others to find answers via google. See:

- [Assign Application Windows to Different Spaces/Desktops](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/105463/assign-application-windows-to-different-spaces-desktops)
- [Is there a way to hide certain apps from the cmd+tab menu?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/92004/is-there-a-way-to-hide-certain-apps-from-the-cmdtab-menu)

Specifically, the one thing you need to care about is CFBundleIdentifier in the app's Contents/Info.plist file. Here is a part from a script that may be useful:

```
  # Change Bundle ID so desktop assignation works. Not sure if this will survive updates.
  # CFBundleIdentifier must contain only alphanumeric (A-Z,a-z,0-9), hyphen (-), and period (.) characters.
  # (Based on fiddling around there also seems to be a length limit.)
  UUID="$(echo $APP | md5sum | awk '{print $1}' | tr [0-9] [A-Z] | cut -c 1-4,29-32)"
  plutil -replace CFBundleIdentifier -string "cdi.$UUID" -- "$RUNTIMES/$APP/Contents/Info.plist"
  #plutil -replace CFBundleName -string "$APP" -- "$RUNTIMES/$APP/Contents/Info.plist"
  #plutil -replace CFBundleDisplayName -string "$APP" -- "$RUNTIMES/$APP/Contents/Info.plist"
  # To check: defaults read ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.spaces.plist app-bindings
```

To see this in some context, see my answer to this question: [Is there a simple way to have separate dock icons for different Chrome Profiles?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/66670/is-there-a-simple-way-to-have-separate-dock-icons-for-different-chrome-profiles/172218#172218)

Comment: OTOH, while the linked pages give some clues about how to solve the problem stated in the question, they don't actually explain *how* to solve it. Can you add this to your answer?

Comment: Updated answer @patrix hope that that's enough. In any case, it's all I know :-)